# Are there ways to optimise multiple if, else if, else statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code, is there anyway to somehow loop through the if, else if and else statements to dynamically populate them somehow (without so many statements, or is this considered good practice)?

```
$('input').each( function () {

    var self = $(this)

    if ( self.attr( 'type' ) === 'email' && supportsInputType ( 'email' ) ) {
            self.data( 'fallback', 'email' )
    } else if ( self.attr( 'type' ) === 'url'  && supportsInputType ( 'url' ) ) {
            self.data( 'fallback', 'url' )
    } else if ( self.attr( 'pattern' ) && supportsAttr ( 'pattern' ) ) {
        self.data( 'fallback', 'pattern' )
    }

})
```

I've omitted my other functions as concentrating on the if/else etc. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  Can you add pseudo-code to illustrate what you're objective is?

Comment: Hey David, well that's what I am trying to achieve from someone's experience giving! :) is there a better way of somehow shortening/compressing if, else if, else statements - so they're basically not written out fully.

Comment: Why do you need the `supportsInputType` function?

Comment: @Blender - the input type support will be inverted (!) - so that it sets data WHEN the attribute exists, but doesn't support. A fallback mechanism for later hooking into the data.

Comment: @Halcyon21: Post the source of `supportsInputType`.

Comment: Ugh... your coding style is so fragmented. Hard to look at.

Comment: @CrazyTrain by that do you mean the spaces? I always liked how jQuery used spaces, a habit that I liked :)

Comment: Yeah, the spaces. I might see value in it if there was no such thing as syntax highlighting, but reading large quantities of code that are so spread out would be a nightmare.

Comment: Agreed, for larger scripts I've adopted it though, for smaller quicker ones I don't use it. Old habits and that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make `supportsInputType` properly handle any type, you could just do something like this:

```
$('input[type]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if (this.type !== $this.attr('type')) {
        $this.data('fallback', type);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Blender, though I need it to match the second parameter as well, if it has the input type, and supports it as well. Is that achievable?

Comment: @Halcyon21: Why? How is `supportsInputType` defined?

Comment: @Halcyon21: Can you explain what the purpose of this code is? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: supportsInputType will return whether the input type is supported by the browser. If it is, the script won't run/continue, if it isn't, I will set data, and then onsubmit look for that data again to validate against.

Comment: @Halcyon21: I get that, but why do you need to check in the first place?

Comment: Because the validator (latter part of the script..) will then run RegEx fallbacks on the elements holding that .data(), based on the input type, if it's email, it will default to an email RegEx, and for the Patten, it will fallback to the RegEx JS - based on the pattern attr.

Comment: @Halcyon21: That's more like it. You might want to take a look at the jQuery Validation Plugin (Google it), as this doesn't look like a good way to approach field validation.

Comment: What makes you say that? And I've seen it before, just we are building our own here :)

Comment: @Halcyon21: Well, I just can't see the purpose of checking the input type like this.

Comment: Well, my theory for example: <input type=email data-email-fallback=someRegExp> - the HTML5 will run the type=email, and the fallback will hook into the specified RegEx fallback. I hope that makes some sense :)!

Comment: @Halcyon21: So why don't you do this from within the validator itself, when you're validating each element of the form? Adding `data-` attributes seems like a hack to me.

Comment: Data-* was just the example of the theory, the actual email fallback is within the validator itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to craft a selector that grabs the inputs by attribute straight away and get rid of `supportInputType`. Something like this (untested):

```
var attrs = ['type=email','type=url','pattern'];

$.each(attrs, function(i,attr) {
  $('input['+ attr +']').data('fallback', attr.replace(/.+=/,''));
});
```

That should probably work with your current code.

Comment: This is similar to what I was thinking could be done. But I definitely need the supportsInputType function in there as well as an && operator.